# Valid foreach loop causing 500 Internal Server Error in valid Ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, foreach

I have a `$products` array:

```
$products = [

    1031 => [
        'id'    => '1031',
        'name'  => 'TR16',
        'price' => 98.75
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'    => '1032',
        'name'  => 'TR16G',
        'price' => 148.75
    ]
];
```

And a $newItemIds array:

```
$newItemIds = [

    1031 => [
        'id'       => 1031,
        'quantity' => 4
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'       => 1032,
        'quantity' => 2
    ]
];
```

I am attempting to loop thru these arrays and modify the `$products` array so it includes `quantity`.

My loop looks like this:

```
foreach($products as &$product) {
    foreach($newItemIds as $key => $value) {
        if ($product['id'] == $value['id']) {
            $product['quantity'] = $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
}
```

At phptester.net, it prints this result (exactly what I want):

```
Array
(
    [1031] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1031
            [name] => TR16
            [price] => 98.75
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [1032] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1032
            [name] => TR16G
            [price] => 148.75
            [quantity] => 2
        )

)
```

Before the loop, I successfully `echo json_encode($products)` back to the `$.ajax` and view this in the console.

```
0: {id: "1031", name: "TR16", price: "98.75"}
1: {id: "1032", name: "TR16G", price: "148.75"}
```

The `$.ajax` request is working.

However, after the loop, when I echo `$products` again to see the modified array (`echo json_encode($products)`), I receive a `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

The Ajax is working; the loop is working, but something is wrong.

If anyone has an idea about what I might be doing wrong, I would appreciate the insight.

Here is all the tested code:

```
<?php

$products = [

    1031 => [
        'id'    => '1031',
        'name'  => 'TR16',
        'price' => 98.75
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'    => '1032',
        'name'  => 'TR16G',
        'price' => 148.75
    ]
];

$newItemIds = [

    1031 => [

        'id'       => 1031,
        'quantity' => 4
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'       => 1032,
        'quantity' => 2
    ]
];  

foreach($products as &$product) {
    foreach($newItemIds as $key => $value) {
        if ($product['id'] == $value['id']) {
            $product['quantity'] = $value['quantity'];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31eab6412a66867b8affdbd118cad1360944bc7c ...seems to work ok on the face of it. Have you missed out some other pertinent detail from your example? By the way if you either check your PHP logs (if you have any) or switch on error reporting, you will be able to see the exact cause of the 500 error - it could be any kind of crash, so the 500 code on its own is not enough info to really help in detail, especially when the code you've shown appears to work ok.

Comment: Most likely a typo or a missing `;`

Comment: However, from a semantic point of view, encoding two separate json objects and echoing them both is likely to confuse your client-side code, because it will expect a single coherent json object/array back, not two separate pieces of data. It won't be parseable by JavaScript. That can't cause a 500 error but it can and will cause JS errors in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that with [array_replace_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)

```
<?php

$products = [

    1031 => [
        'id'    => '1031',
        'name'  => 'TR16',
        'price' => 98.75
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'    => '1032',
        'name'  => 'TR16G',
        'price' => 148.75
    ]
];  


$newItemIds = [

    1031 => [
        'id'       => 1031,
        'quantity' => 4
    ],
    1032 => [
        'id'       => 1032,
        'quantity' => 2
    ]
];

$products_with_quantity = array_replace_recursive($products, $newItemIds);
print_r($products_with_quantity);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/YQQpF

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 500 error gone. `$products` array has four objects instead of adding `quantity` to the two objects. `0: {id: "1031", name: "TR16", price: "98.75"}
1: {id: "1032", name: "TR16G", price: "148.75"}
1031: {id: "1031", quantity: "3"}
1032: {id: "1032", quantity: "2"}`

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: If it did help, accept the answer, so that the next person that has this problem can look here

Comment: It does help. Always great to learn a new function, and the definition seems spot on. I would still like to understand why the foreach loop fails.